# Why is fzf failing in this case

Tags: brew

I've found [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to be a very useful utility, but for some reason it is failing me in this one particular instance.

```
$ brew outdated | fzf -m --tac | brew upgrade
```

Instead of letting me choose which items to upgrade, it displays a menu for a moment, and then proceeds to upgrade *everything*.  I've never had it behave this way before.  What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the selection to `stdout` and pipe it over to `brew upgrade`, but `brew upgrade` does not use `stdin`. The command updates just everything.

You will need something like this to add the selection as arguments:

```
brew outdated | fzf -m --tac | xargs brew upgrade
```

Comment: This solves the initial problem.  It should not be used _as is_, however, since hitting <kbd>escape</kbd> in `fzf` will result in brew aggressively trying to upgrade everything, and `⌃C` only interrupting one thing at a time.  (Very bad UX on the part of Homebrew in that case!)